# gitignore particular file format in all directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude a file format e.g `*.simg` in all directories. I have tried to add `*.simg` in `.gitignore` but still the files are visible in `git status`.

I have a folder structure as follow and .gitignore file is in root directory:

```
-service-foo/foo.simg
-service-bar/bar.simg
-composite-service/service-foobar/foobar.simg
-.gitignore
```

How can I exclude the format in all directories?

**EDIT 1:**

`.gitignore` file as follow:

```
HELP.md
target/
.mvn/
.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**

### SINGULARITY simg###
*.simg
```

When I do `git status` I get:

```
javaadmin@THNJAVA11:~/server/airadhi-server$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   composite-service/foobar.simg
        modified:   composite-service/service-foobar/foobar.recipe
        deleted:    service-foo/foo.simg
        modified:   service-bar/bar.simg

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Can you show your gitignore and the `git status` output ?

Comment: @ZeissS I edited my question and added `gitignore` and `git status` output. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done in your `.gitignore` is correct. You need to remove the files from the staging area by doing a `git rm -r --cached <filename/pathspec>` and then commit the changes. When there will be any changes in the files next time, they won't cause trouble :)

You might want to refer to [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.27.0-rc2/Documentation/gitfaq.txt#L209) as well.

Best

Comment: Thanks `git rm --cached *.simg` works for me.